# Find the width and length of a rectangle (Java)

Tags: java, class, inheritance, methods, polymorphism

Before you read ahead this question is for my homework so it will be specific.

I am writing some code that uses polymorphism to display the properties of a rectangle (ie, x, y, height...). The code uses inheritance and polymorphism to achieve the results. Everything like the width and topleftX point is being determined using an algorithm that picks a random integer from a specified range. How I tried to fix the problem is to write a getWidth() and getLength() method to the rectangle class. I put in a super(); for the other class that gets the X and Y coordinates.

The problem that I am having is that I am unsure of how to access the classes that will give me the width and height of the rectangle. Inside of the methods that I have written the super() displays an error and it says "(x,y) cannot be applied to ()" which I am unsure of what it means. I assume that the values are private and I cannot access them, but in the class with the implementation, there are no private instances, so I am confused.

This is my code below:

```
    public GeometricShapeTester(){
        shapes = new GeometricShape[20];
        Random rand = new Random();
        int option;
        final int COORD = 50;
        final int LENGTH1 = 50;
        final int LENGTH2 = 100;
        for(int i=0; i<shapes.length; i++){
            option=rand.nextInt(4);
            switch(option){
                case 0:
                    shapes[i]= new Rectangle(
                            rand.nextInt(COORD),
                            rand.nextInt(COORD),
                            rand.nextInt(LENGTH2),
                            rand.nextInt(LENGTH2));
                    break;
                case 1:
                    shapes[i]= new Square(
                            rand.nextInt(COORD),
                            rand.nextInt(COORD),
                            rand.nextInt(LENGTH2));
                    break;
                case 2:
                    shapes[i]= new Oval(
                            rand.nextInt(COORD),
                            rand.nextInt(COORD),
                            rand.nextInt(LENGTH1),
                            rand.nextInt(LENGTH2));
                    break;
                case 3:
                    shapes[i]= new Circle(
                            rand.nextInt(COORD),
                            rand.nextInt(COORD),
                            rand.nextInt(LENGTH1));
            }
        }
    }

    public GeometricShape[] getShapes(){
        return shapes;
    }


}

abstract class GeometricShape{
    private int x;
    private int y;
    public GeometricShape(int x,int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public int getX(){
        return x;
    }
    public int getY(){
        return y;
    }
    abstract public double getArea();
    abstract public String toString();
}

class Rectangle extends GeometricShape{
    public Rectangle(int x, int y, int nextInt, int nextInt1) {
        super();
    }

    public getWidth(){
        super();

    }

    public getLength(){
        super();
    }



    @Override
    public double getArea() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Rectangle: [x:" + getX() + ", y:" + getY() + ", width: + " + getWidth() + " height: " + getHeight() + "]";
    }
    // body
}
```

Comment: Wouldn’t a rectangle need to store its length and width and use them to calculate its area? Since this is a common polymorphism example maybe searching for implementation ideas might help?

Comment: Are you sure you understand what you're doing with the `super` keyword? Your code is calling the constructor of the GeometricShape super class in multiple spots. Pretty sure you mean to call `super.someMethodName()` rather than calling the constructor multiple times.

Comment: In your code, I could not understand where the width and height are stored.
If you want to store it in Rectangle class, then you can directly access it by its method getWidth() or if you are storing it in GeometricShape, you can call super.getWidth() to access it.

Comment: Your error comes from tyinging to access a super class constructor with no parameters when you haven't programmed one.